# Modularize the soapui test suites with groovy script which is written in eclipse, create a jar file of the groovy script and call it into soapui

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, soapui

I need to create a sample Soap request by calling the endpoint URL and give the necessary login and password info and then send a request and get a response in XML. I'm writing the groovy script in eclipse IDE and creating a jar file and call that jar file into SoapUI and call the code within the jar file into SoapUI.

Here is the sample code:

```
package com.xyz.demo

class ABC {
public setUP() {
    // set data
    def url = new URL("https://qwertywq.asmx").openConnection();
    if(soapaction != null) connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapaction);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Text/xml");
    String AuthorizationString = "Basic " + (username + ":" +  password).bytes.encodeBase64();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationString);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(xml);
    wr.close();

    // Get the response
        String response;
        InputStream responseStream;
        try {
            responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
            success = 1;
        } catch( IOException e ) {
            success = 0;
            if( connection.getResponseCode() == 500 ) {
                responseStream = connection.getErrorStream();
            } else throw e;
        }

    response = responseStream.getText("utf-8");
    responseStream.close();
    return response;
}
```

I am getting an error and how should I resolve this? Is there any other way to achieve my goal? Please let me know.

The Output:
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: This script or class could not be run.
It should either:
- have a main method,
- be a JUnit test or extend GroovyTestCase,
- implement the Runnable interface,
- or be compatible with a registered script runner. Known runners:
  * org.apache.groovy.plugin.DefaultRunners$Junit3TestRunner
  * org.apache.groovy.plugin.DefaultRunners$Junit3SuiteRunner
  * org.apache.groovy.plugin.DefaultRunners$Junit4TestRunner

Comment: When I add a main method to the above code I am getting another error. Please help me to sort out the best way to deal with this task.

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.qwertyqw.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String; ) values: [[]]

Comment: You've tagged the question with `soapui`, but are you actually using that product or just the SOAP protocol?

Comment: Add soapUI code, version and how are you adding the jar to it.

Comment: If this is the source you are trying to compile and run, it has a number of syntax errors.  If this is an edited excert, it is hard to answer your question without additional detail.  What you have provided is not runnable as a Java Application or a Groovy Script within Eclipse.